# how to pick dynamic textbox values created by javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have inventory sale form where I am selecting items from list,
I am getting there values and assigning the same to newly created textbox by clicking on each item using javascript
customer requires different items with different quantity's, so i am using javascript for that purpose,
when customer click on an item it creates text box which will take
number of quantitys to process further, now the issue is how i will pick it up in php file,
like before there was two boxes and I know the name of them so I set it as
`if isset($_POST['txtboxname']) && isset($_POST['anothertxtboxname']))` but now
the textbox is been creating dynamically, Items in list are coming from
database, how should I handle that?

```
 <script>

 function createFunc() {

    var getForm = document.getElementById("theForm");    
    var getElem = document.getElementById("selectMultiple");
    var optValue = getElem.options[getElem.selectedIndex].value;
    var optName = getElem.options[getElem.selectedIndex].text;

    var qtyDiv = document.getElementById("quantityDiv");

    var createInput = document.createElement("input");
        createInput.type = "text";
        createInput.name = optValue;

      qtyDiv.appendChild(createInput);

    }

    </script>

    <html>

    <form id="theForm" action="testpht.php" method="POST"    
    enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <select id="selectMultiple" name="select_pro[]" class="formTxtInputmany"  
    multiple="multiple"  onchange="createFunc()" >

    <option>SELECT PRODUCT</option>    

    <?php 

    include 'mysql_connect.php';
    $objDbClass = new DBConfig();
    $conn = $objDbClass->get_db_pdo_func();

    $sql = "SELECT pro_id,pro_name,quantity FROM products ORDER BY pro_name    
    ASC";

    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arrlength = count($result);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++){

    ?>        

    <option value="<?php echo $result[$x]['pro_id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $result[$x]['pro_name']; ?> <?php } ?>

    </option> </select>

   <div id="quantityDiv"></div>

   input value="submit" type="submit" class="SubmtBtn"> </form>
   </html>
```

Comment: You can set the name of each text box to its `pro_name`? that way in PHP you can know how many options were there and for each option check if any textbox was set with that name

Comment: if customer choose 150 items so i have to setup code for 150 but what if he choose one 2 or 3 items, I am little confuse

Comment: I think, you must go with AJAX. @mohsin